# Generating nested namespaces using CodeDom with C#

Tags: c#, codedom

I'd like to use CodeDom to generate some code that contains some custom enums in nested namespaces.

Example:

```
namespace Enums
{
    namespace MoreSpecificEnums
    {
         public enum AnEnum
         {
             FirstValue = 0,
             SecondValue = 1,
         }
    }
}
```

I can create the Enums namespace fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to add the MoreSpecificEnums namespace inside it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
        CodeNamespace enumNamespace = new CodeNamespace("Enums");
        compileUnit.Namespaces.Add(enumNamespace);
        CodeNamespace msEnumNamespace = new CodeNamespace("MoreSpecificEnums");
        // Now I'm stuck, where do I plug msEnumNamespace in?
        // enumNamespace doesn't have a Namespaces array like the compileUnit.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're right that this is not possible.

What is possible is to generate this equivalent code:

```
namespace Enums.MoreSpecificEnums
{
     public enum AnEnum
     {
         FirstValue = 0,
         SecondValue = 1,
     }
}
```